# Howto display iPad keyboard when application starts?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a simple (one view) application without any TextFileds. How can I show a native virtual keyboard when application starts?

Comment: Why do you want to show the keyboard if there isn't anywhere to type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an invisible text field and give it focus. May I ask why you want a visible keyboard if there isn't a control for which the user will expect to receive the text?

Comment: Oh, yes I want to develop a simple example to show non-standard situation.